# How can I delete not verified emails in Firebase in web?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I created a function that signs up with email and password in Angular 6 with Firebase.

Then I send an email to verify email, then some times user go to his email and verify.

That's sound good, others don't go to verify email so it's still in my Firebase.

I want any function inside Firebase that automatically remove emails that not verified for more than two days.

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely no way of doing this for Clients. You will have to use the NodeJS Firebase Admin SDK for this.

I don't think there's a straight-forward way of doing this. You could try chaining the `listUsers` method along with `deleteUser` method. Before deleting a user, you could check if the user is not verified.

Once this script is ready, just deploy it as a Firebase Cloud Function.

I'm not sure how to run this every 2 days.

I'm not sure if even this would work. But you might want to give this a try:

```
function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
  // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
  admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
      listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
        const user = userRecord.toJSON();
        if (!user.emailVerified) {
          admin.auth().deleteUser(user.uid)
            .then(function() {
              console.log("Successfully deleted user");
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
            });
        }
      });
      if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken)
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error listing users:", error);
    });
}

// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
listAllUsers();
```

Comment: i need confirmed function please

Comment: how  to use the NodeJS Firebase Admin SDK for this.